# CPU hitting 100% when flash or game is running after dropping laptop

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, laptop-repair, gaming

I have a quad core Lenovo with 8GB memory running windows 7 x64 with NVidia quadro 880

Everything was working great until one day I would be playing a game and the CPU would max out for a few minutes.  I'd be able to play the game for a few minutes and then it would max out.

The one thing that may have triggered it is I gently dropped it one day. The keyboard became dislodged, so I went through and made sure all the connections of the components were secure to the motherboard and tested the memory.  All of the fans appear to be working and the mother board isn't getting that hot and the video card is barely being taxed.

Everything works fine if I don't play a game (flash or otherwise).

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  Should I send it back for warranty service?

Thanks!

Comment: This could simply be a case of dust in the air filters, have you tried looking for instructions to disassemble your laptop and checking for clogs or clumps of dust that could be causing your laptop to overheat and throttle down?

Comment: I remember answering this question before yet I do not remember my answer and I could not find it.

Comment: It's not overheating.

Comment: How are you sure its not overheating ?   (I put to you that if the bump dislodged the CPU heatsink slightly, it could cause a local buildup of heat which would translate into lower temperatures across the rest of the machine, but the CPU itself overheating because it can't disipate the heat.

Comment: I ran a heat monitor during the jumps.  none of the temperature monitors went up at all.  The GPU (which seems to be the impetus for the CPU increase) is one of the coolest components, actually got cooler during one bump

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I send it back for warranty service?

Yes.  Why?  Three reasons.

1. If it is on warranty, any modifications or breaking of the seal will void the warranty.
2. If they decide that since you are responsible for the damage, that they are not responsible for repairing it (IE, your warranty covers manufacturing defects, not user ones), you are back in the same boat of looking to repair it yourself anyway... which is where you started.
3. > I gently dropped it one day

I have heard this way too many times.  *I only dropped it a little* or maybe *I didn't drop it very far* or how about *I just tripped on the cord, and it came off the desk... not that hard though.*  No one ever thinks that the sudden impact has anything to do with the sudden performance drop of their **complex and expensive** electronic device.  Do you know why things like dropping a laptop aren't covered by most warranties?  Because they are common, and they are virtually guaranteed to damage something to the point of requiring replacement.

Now I know... if a drop isn't covered by a warranty, why send it back?  Well.... I know it's not all that ethical, and it's definitely not honest, but if you omit the fact that you dropped it and the laptop does not show any physical damage from the impact, Lenovo might just repair it on warranty.  Unless you have money to burn, having Lenovo pay to replace a hard drive (or god forbid something worse) is better than you paying to replace it... even if **you** were the cause of the damage in their eyes... aka the drop was not a manufacturing defect.

Did you know that your hard drive has a warning written on it not to subject it to exactly this kind of shock?

There are a couple of possibilities, and in all honesty the laptop should be taken into a shop at the very least.  But, since it is on warranty, that shop should be Lenovo.

Comment: Gently is a big overstatement. EVERYTHING is working fine though, except for a few graphics intensive games so I was hoping it would be something simple.  I didn't want to be without it for too long.

Comment: Ok then.  Gently, as in, so insignificant that it didn't actually damage anything at all... and your laptop is experiencing issues that have nothing to do with the impact.  Doesn't change the fact that the laptop is suddenly not performing as it should and it is still on warranty... both of which warrant it being sent back for service.  The fact that you don't want to be without it that long, that's kind of irrelevant.  I suppose you can take it to a local shop and have them perform a diagnostic on it.  You'll just be paying for that though.

Comment: sorry, understatement not overstatement.  The keyboard managed to dislodge itself. I'll probably end up having to send it back if it continues.

Answer (score 1):

When you say maxed out do you mean the fan is running flat out, if so it sounds like your course cooler isn't seated properly. You'll have to take your laptop apart again and reseat it possibly reapplying thermal paste.

Comment: The CPU is hitting 100% and everything starts...jittering.